AWS advice needed for approach to building a MAUI - API -SqlServer C# app
I am building an app on AWS with several components.  In general I'm a C# / MS developer and my knowledge expands outwards from there.
I'm building a MAUI mobile app that will post/get from an API.  This API will crud a SqlServer database.  And there will be an Angular website for viewing and managing the db too.
After doing a tour of Google, Azure and a few smaller unknowns, I decided to go with AWS - that's decided even if there are cheaper good value options.  I like their consistent approach and tutorials, single billing etc.
Now the architecture questions looms again and I'm hoping to tap into the experience of others to save losing too much time exploring the wrong options.
Effectively I want to simply post/get json from a phone to the online server:  Maui -> API -> SqlServer.
Fundamentally everything is built locally and now I want to move it online.  How do I do it?..   Initially I thought about shoving everything into a container or many containers?
Now I'm challenged with the idea of do I use the AWS API Gateway?
Do I use SqlServer in a container or AWS RDS SqlServer??
Do I use Auth0 or the AWS IAM to manage n public users?
Also to consider:   I have, say, a policeman app that needs full bandwidth and top performance always to hit the api, and then there's a public app that can run slower and should be tweaked separately.  Do I put these in different containers?, Different services??
The biggest Q atm is sqlserver and APIs in containers or AWS products?
A good answer here could save me days of work and tonnes of energy - Thank you  :)

"Do I use SqlServer in a container or AWS RDS SqlServer??" RDS absolutely. You get a ton of built-in disaster recovery, backups, failover, etc. from RDS, that is really difficult to build yourself by piecing together containers.

Your C# app could certainly run in containers. I would start by getting it all running locally in a docker-compose environment, to work out any issues with running your app in an container. Or you could just use something like Elastic Beanstalk to manage more of the infrastructure for you. It's really up to you.

AWS IAM is for internal AWS users, not public app users. AWS Cognito would be the thing that is similar to Auth0.

Everything else is your question is just going to be subjective, like your use of API Gateway is entirely up to you, if the features of API Gateway are something you actually need or not, etc.

Hi @MarkB thanks for all of that - I'm a AWS Newbie, yes you remind me that Cognito is the tool I am thinking of.    I like how everything is connected in AWS and their security and monitoring is very reassuring and makes me want to keep it all in the same bubble.  I did have this app running before on a hSphere host and it was ddos'd and open to all sorts of assaults, so I'd be keen to avoid all of that again.

So putting my APIs in a container is reasonable?  I can throttle these up/down as needed?

Does the Policeman app go in a separate container for maximum performance?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For your use case, I would consider this approach.
Mobile app -> API Gateway -> Lambda implemented in C# -> RDS.
This is known as a serverless solultion as you do not have to manage servers or containers, etc.
The mobile app is the user-facing component that runs on the user's device, whether it's an iOS or Android device. The mobile app will handle the user interface, user interactions, and local data storage (if needed). It will communicate with the backend services through an API to fetch data, perform actions, and synchronize data.
The API Gateway serves as the entry point for the mobile app to access the backend services. It provides a standardized and secure interface for the mobile app to interact with the backend. The API Gateway can handle tasks such as authentication, authorization, request routing, and load balancing. It can also perform request transformation, caching, and other cross-cutting concerns before forwarding the requests to the backend.
The AWS Lambda functions, implemented in C#, represent the business logic and data processing components of the backend. These serverless functions are triggered by the API Gateway when the mobile app makes requests. They can perform various tasks, such as querying the database, processing data, and returning the appropriate responses to the mobile app. The use of C# in the Lambda functions are supported.

I luv this answer just because it's the opposite of what the other guy said :D
You both agree on RDS so I have that setup and ready.  I tried the API Gateway but the editor isn't very C# friendly.  I'll spend today on it again though and see how it goes.  Lambda is a new approach for me too so I'll try it out.

I did this guy's course https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I581mkYRRZA&list=PLBMCyCQ4nalYgsvnM2I7Y7cP5bqgjdfB5  and I'm now an AWS fan.  Although I'm not sure how my FREE Tier is already costing $20 from just development work? Maybe Free is T2.micro but only T3.micro exists nowadays? Or maybe it's this guys approach to setting it up from a script??  Anyway, I'm a AWS fan now!!!
